# How to calculate score for each entry based on criterion and select the ones with biggest score?

Tags: sql, database

I want to write a small script which would scrap user comments from a small forum and store some statistic data in database. Basically I am interested in how often users are using different words in their comments.

Imagine the following schema:

word

- id
- text

user

- id
- username

user_words

- word_id
- user_id
- count (how much times user used the word in all his comments on the forum)

After this I would like to create a query which would select me 5 similar users from database. To be more specific:

Imagine that we have an average frequency usage of following words in all comments of forum:

- word1: 4%
- word2: 1%
- word3: 10%
- ...

For specific user the frequency of these words is:

- word1: 15%
- word2: 2%
- word3: 1%
- ...

Programmatically I will find user words with the biggest difference from average values. In my case these words are:

- word1 (15% over average 4%)
- word3 (1% over average 10%)

Now I want to find the users with similar usage frequencies on word1 and word3. For example:

user1:

- word1: 13%
- word3: 2%

user2:

- word1: 5%
- word3: 9%

user1 is much more similar to our original user. The similarity can be calculated as deltas sum:

- user1: |15% - 13%| + |1% - 2%| = 2 + 1 = 3
- user2: |15 - 9%|+ |1% - 9%| = 6 + 8 = 14

The difference with user1 is much much smaller. So user1 is much more similar to original user.

Now. Imagine I have thousands of users in database. I would like to select 5 users (limit) ordering them by score (where score is calculated in a way I showed above).

The problem is that I have no idea which mechanisms exists in SQL in order to achieve this (DBMS doesn't matter). Could you please give me a peace of advice, which mechanism I should use in order to assign some virtual "score" to each user and select ordering by it? I just need to know in which direction I should go, what should I read about.

Comment: My advice is to pare down your question to something _minimal_, where a reader can get the gist of what you are asking in under 60 seconds.

Comment: You can do math in SQL--sounds like you'd want to do a query that produces the score for each user, and then use the results of that query for further processing. Read up on subqueries, common table expressions (if you're using sql server), math in select clauses, etc. That'll get you going.

Comment: That's exactly what I want - to produce the score and then select users limiting + ordering by this score. Never heard about common table expressions before. Will read about it, thank you!

Comment: Can I suggest you read about "full text search" here is an example https://www.compose.com/articles/indexing-for-full-text-search-in-postgresql/ and note the list on "tokenizers" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-parsers.html your first hurdle is breaking-up comment strings into constituent words and storing this to arrive at the base data.

Comment: @Used_By_Already thanks for your comment. Yes, of course, each comment should be processed and split into words. My question is not related to this process since I understand how to do it properly more or less. The biggest question for me here is how to work with comment processing results in order to calculate "similarity score" between users in SQL query.

Comment: If you have the ability to split-up the comments into words, then you already have some table structure in mind, and if that is true then **sample data** and **expected results** would help you get answers for specific problems you may face. As it stands now this question is really very broad (not even dbms specific either).

Answer (score 0):

First things first would be to be able to count occurence of string right? What I would do is JOIN your words table to comment table, then call a scalar function to count the words per comment then just sum it up group by userid and wordid

Please see sample scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountNoOfString
(
    @searchString nvarchar(max),
    @valueString nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    return (LEN(@searchString)-LEN(REPLACE(@searchString,@valueString ,'')))/LEN(@valueString)
END
```

From there it would be easy to get the metrics that you need